# Running .net core web app on AWS Beanstalk - file write permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, file-permissions, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Ok, so I've got a web application written in .NET Core which I've deployed to the AWS Elastic beanstalk which was pretty easy, but I've already hit a snag.

The application fetches JSON data from an external source and writes to a local file, currently to wwwroot/data/data.json under the project root.  Once deployed to AWS, this functionality is throwing an access denied exception when it tries to write the file.

I've seen something about creating a folder called .ebextensions with a config file with some container commands to set permissions to certain paths/files after deployment, and I've tried doing that, but that does not seem to do anything for me - I don't even know if those commands are even being executed so I have no idea what's happening, if anything.

This is the config file I created under the .ebextensions folder:

```
{
    "container_commands": {
        "01-aclchange": {
            "command": "icacls \"C:/inetpub/AspNetCoreWebApps/app/wwwroot/data\" /grant DefaultAppPool:(OI)(CI)",
         }
    }
}
```

The name of the .config file matches the applicatio name in AWS, but I also read somewhere that the name does not matter, as long as it has the .config extension.

Has anyone successfully done something like this?  Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Prefaced with the fact I know nothing about EB, might I suggest you don't write to the filesystem at all? It can be brittle and have problems like you are seeing. Why not push the file into S3 storage for example?

Comment: That might very well be an option.  The original reason for using the file system was to avoid having to use a database just for this, since the app otherwise does not need a database at all.  I might have a look at the S3 storage, thanks.

Comment: Just had a quick look at the S3 storage and it seems to be exactly what I need.  I'm going to use that instead of the file system.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: OK, I've answered and cleaned up my comments here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to fix permission issues writing to the local storage within AWS Elastic Beanstalk, I would instead suggest using something like [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) for storing files. Some benefits would be:

- Not having to worry about file permissions.
- S3 files are persistent.
- You may run into issues with losing local files when you republish your application.
- If you ever move to using something like containers, you will lose the file every time the container is taken down.
- S3 is incredibly cheap to use.